# Get pull requests (or merge requests) by date range (from now to past date) - GitHub/GitLab REST API

Tags: rest, api, github, gitlab

We want to get pull requests OR merge requests from now to a date in the past ("created_at" or "merged_at" date).

Is there any way to get a list of data that "created_at" or "merged_at" from a date (Ex: 2019-02-02) to now? If yes, how it looks like when using curl command?

You can see the JSON structure from the links listed below. Thank you very much.

Ex: "created_at" >= 2019-02-02

- GitHub: https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.19/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests

```
curl "https://github.com/api/v3/repos/{repoIdOrName}/pulls?state=closed" -X GET -H "Authorization: token XXXX" -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.sailor-v-preview+json"
```

- GitLab: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#list-merge-requests

```
curl "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/{repoIdOrName}/merge_requests?target_branch=master" -XGET -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: XXXX"
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the `.../<owner>/<repo>/pulls` route doesn't currently allow this kind of query. To accomplish this, you need to use the general-purpose `.../issues` route.  In GitHub, a *Pull Request* is an instance of an *Issue*.

Adapt and curl the following URL (substitute `<owner>` and `<repo>` for your own):

`https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo:<owner>/<repo>+is:pr+created:>=2020-08-15`

A few remarks:

- I've left out the authentication part; use the strategy that fits your use case.
- The structure of the result is different: the `.../pulls` route returns an array, while the `.../issues` route returns an object with an embedded array in the field `items`.  Also, the returned objects contain less information than what's returned by the `.../pulls` route.  For example, the `merged_at` field is absent, as is the `_links` field. However, in each PR object, there is a `.pull_request.url` field containing an URL that will return all the PR data you would get from the `.../pulls` URL, in the same format.
- If you need to filter by the `updated_at` date field, just put `updated` instead of `created` in the above query. `closed` and `merged` seem to also work.
- You can perform sorting of the results by appending something like `&sort=created&order=asc` to the query URL.
- Pagination is handled the same way: if your query results contain too many items, the link to the next page is provided in the header (use `-I` argument with curl), that you can grep with the regex `'^link:.*?<([^>]+)>; rel="next".+'` to extract the next page's link in the first group.

Answer (score 0):

For gitlab, according to the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#list-merge-requests) you mentioned, you could use `created_after` parameter. so:

```
curl "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/{repoIdOrName}/merge_requests?target_branch=master&created_after=2020-02-02" -XGET -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: XXXX"
```

should do the trick